# Java: Linked List deleteFirst() method

Tags: java, reference

I have a conceptual question. In the `deleteFirst()` instance method , my understanding is that `first` is a reference to say, link_A, and `temp` is a reference to `first` (a reference to a reference to link_A). In the second line of the method, `first` becomes a reference to `first.next`. Now, when it returns `temp`, shouldn't `temp` be a reference to `first` which is a reference to `first.next`?

What is my misconception here?

```
class Link{
    public int iData; 
    public double dData; 
    public Link next;

     public Link(int id, double dd) // constructor 
     {
       iData = id; 
       dData = dd; 
     }
}

class LinkList{
    private Link first;

    public LinkList(){
        first = null; 

    public Link deleteFirst(){
        Link temp = first;
        first = first.next;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Temp is assigned to the first, and first is then assigned to the next value. so when you return temp you are returning the value of the original first, and the list is updated to be the next in the list. Although why it is returning the Node rather than the data I am not sure.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure but you could use Link temp = first.clone(); on the first method which basically copies 'first' and assigns that object to temp variable so when you return, you return the original 'first'.

Answer (score 1):

Variables do not reference other variables. They reference the *object* thats stored in that variable.

`temp` references the object stored in `first`. You then change the reference of `first` to contain the object stored in `first.next`. This means `temp` will also reference the object stored in`first.next`, since it's referencing the object stored in `first`, which is now the same object stored in `first.next`

Comment: So, you are saying that Java never allows the situation, where there is a reference to another reference ?

Comment: @mynameisJEFF That's exactly what I'm saying. All references are to objects, and will never be to another reference. This is considered "pass-by-value", which differs from "pass-by-reference" systems. For more info on the differences between the two, check out this question. If you want a trick to get by the "pass-by-value" situation, there are many tutorials online

Answer (score 0):

"first" is its own variable that refers to the "first.next" in the second line. Note: watch out for NPE 'cause initially "first" could be null.
"temp" points to what "first" initially pointed to. And continues to point to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to return the reference to first(point to the second item of the previous link list), because the member variable first of the LinkList is already record the head of the list and when you delete the first node, you always has some thing to do with it, so it should return the item itself.
   You can reference to the source code of LinkedList in jdk:

```
public class LinkedList<E>
extends AbstractSequentialList<E>
implements List<E>, Deque<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable{

.....

transient Node<E> first;



public E removeFirst() {
    final Node<E> f = first;
    if (f == null)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    return unlinkFirst(f);
}

private E unlinkFirst(Node<E> f) {
    // assert f == first && f != null;
    final E element = f.item;
    final Node<E> next = f.next;
    f.item = null;
    f.next = null; // help GC
    first = next;
    if (next == null)
        last = null;
    else
        next.prev = null;
    size--;
    modCount++;
    return element;
}


....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has what is known at the "Garbage Collector" and unlike other languages where you have to collected the "garbage"(or in this instance an unused variable) yourself, java collects that unused heap and temp this points to the (NEXT) memory location in your link.